# Call directive controller methods from outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I write a directive that provide a tab functionality, I use latest version of AngularJS (v1).
In my directive I have a controller that expose an api to a children directives, the scope is isolated in all directives:

**Parent Directive**

```
scope: {},
controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.values = [];

   this.addValue = function(value) {
        $scope.values.push(value);
   }
}
```

**Child Directive on link function**

```
scope: {},
transclude: true,
template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
replace: true,
link: function(scope, element, attr, parentCtrl)
{
    parentCtrl.addValues('test')
}
```

In child directive I have a custom html with own controller:
**TestCtrl**

```
function TestCtrl($scope){
    var vm = this;
    ... other logic
}
```

**Implementation**

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as t">
          <button ng-click="addValues('new_test')"></button>
      </div>
   </child>
</parent>
```

I need to call "addValues" method (inside directive controller) on click on my button.

How to organise the code to make this?

Comment: Change controller to the component and pass method there using binding with '&' syntax

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Please can you add a few example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.controller('root', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = function () {
        console.log('i am clicked');
    }
});

module.component('child', {
    template: '<button type="button" data-ng-click="$ctrl.click()">Click me</button>',
    controller: myController,
    bindings: {
        onClick: '&'
    }
});

function myController() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.click = function () {
        this.onClick();
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="app">

    <div data-ng-controller="root">
        <child data-on-click="test()"></child>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is just an example
[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) you can read more.
Hope this helps.

MAy be it will be usefull to read about angular's best practice [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Comment: Thank you! But maybe i not explain correctly. I need to call "addValue" method (inside in my parent directive - controller) in my custom html injected on child directive. Can i do it?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You wont to define some function inside html (that will be moved to the transcluded slot) and then, call bind this "call" to the real function inside wrapper?

Comment: Correctly! I have a tabs system and i need, inside transcluded html, to move through tab by a click.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
Check last examples seems they are exactly you asked about